# How do I set a limit on the number of files Linux can have open?

Tags: open-files, limit

I plan to run a Java app using `nohup ... &`. The limit must apply to commands like this.

Comment: But this caused an error in my java program

Answer (score 7):

Most systems use [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules), and have the `pam_limits` module set limits based on `/etc/security/limits.conf`. The per-user limit for open files is called `nofile`. You can set it for every user or for a particular user or group, and you can set a limit that the user can override (soft limit) and another that only root can override (hard limit). The [documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_limits.html) and the `limits.conf` man page have the details. For example, to raise the limit to 50000 for everyone, put this line in `/etc/limits.conf` (the setting takes effect when you log in):

```
* - nofile 50000
```

Comment: within `limits.conf` do `* hard nofile 50000` and/or `* soft nofile 50000`.  I don't know the technical difference between hard and soft and have always done both.

Comment: within SLES 11.4 using tcsh for example, one can do `limit descriptors 50000` to change the value within the given terminal window/session.

Comment: @ron -` in the second column sets both the soft and the hard limit. You only need to set them separately if you want different values. A soft limit can be changed at any time by running the `ulimit` command (called `limit` in csh). An unprivileged user can never go higher than the hard limit.

Comment: if i only set the hard, does the soft value remain the default?  if I only set soft and not hard, does hard remain default value or inherently equal soft value?  Can I set soft > hard?  The soft is the real value that is in effect?  sorry for the questions.

Comment: @ron The soft limit is automatically capped at the hard limit. If you only set the hard limit, then this sets the soft limit to max(default_soft_limit, actual_hard_limit).

Answer (score 4):

you can add `fs.file-max = <your number>` into `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Then reboot.

Comment: cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max is 169203，but ulimit -n is 1024

Comment: No need to reboot. Just run `sysctl fs.file-max=123456`. (`/etc/sysctl.conf` is read at boot time by a script that calls `sysctl` on the contents.)

Answer (score 3):

```
ulimit -n
```

can modify per process settings and

```
/proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

or the sysctl variable called `fs.file-max` can be used to read and set the system-wide value

Comment: cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max is 169203，but ulimit -n is 1024

Answer (score 1):

You can use ulimit for this:

http://bloggerdigest.blogspot.com/2006/10/purpose-of-ulimit-linux-command.html

Although you should make sure that opening so many file handles is absolutely necessary before resorting to such adjustments. Increasing the maximum file handles just because you have forgotten to do an inputstream.close() in a loop is only going to delay the underlying problem.

Comment: I want to connect to lots of clients

Answer (score 1):

Use ulimit(Bash command - man bash or find similar for your shell) per program instance. Do not use global system limits if you don't know what are you doing - possible DoS.

Comment: In SLES 11.4 I have set `nofile` in `limits.conf` to be 100000 successfully.  I can attest that setting too large a value prevented subsequent log in with SSH and I had to boot from dvd to correct that value in limits.conf to recover the system.

Answer (score 0):

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

And add a line at the end of file

```
ulimit -n 169203
```